# <core-localstorage> overwrites value get from url

Tags: polymer

I use `<core-localstorage>` to store some values, but sometimes I want to set these values to url parameters in lifecycle callback `ready`(or other), in this case I don't want the previous values saved by `<core-localstorage>` overwrite new values. Now I can only set values after event `core-localstorage-load` fired, are there any other methods? Thanks!

Comment: Some code to work with would be great.